# Delphi copy files to systemdir problem in Windows 7

Tags: delphi, uac

i can use the copyfile(); function to copy a file to c:/windows/system32 on windows xp but then i use the function on windows 7 i cant copy it:o the file wont come there....

i had the same problem with writing and reading registery but fixed it by declaring a WOW key $0100 ...

i think the problem is uac but not sure.. could somebody explain me that:D?

Comment: Your 3 step guide to dealing with UAC. 1. Add a manifest to your app to make sure that you aren't virtualized. 2. Stop writing to system32, program files etc. 3. Stop writing to HKLM.

Answer (score 6):

That is indeed because of UAC. It is called [File/Folder](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/folder-virtualization-concepts-windows-vista) or [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Virtualization. It is done for legacy applications who don't yet respect the new UAC rules (e.g. not writing in system folders unless you are an administrator).

By creating a manifest file you switch off this virtualization. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx). This can be a seperate file or be embedded into the exe. Newer Delphi versions already generate executables containing such a manifest and have requestedExecutionLevel set to asInvoker. This normally does not allow writing in those locations, unless users specifically run your program as an administrator. Setting it to requireAdministrator does allow writing in those locations, but also means users have to confirm they want to run your program as an administrator.

Answer (score 5):

It's indeed UAC that's preventing you from copying files to the system32 folder. You have to ask yourself why you want to copy files there. A normal application should *never* copy files to the system32 folder.

Sometimes during install you might want to copy dll's there, but even that is legacy behaviour. Should you really want to copy files there, you should request Elevation at the start of the application.

Comment: Hmmm - Many Delphi component installers install the .bpl files to System32. It's normal :)

Comment: They do not. Modern Delphi versions have a setting in Tools > Options where the output directory for BPL's is defined. This is (at least on XE7, and most likely since D2009) a subdirectory of the BDS folder in AppData, ProgramData or the userfolder, depending on your installation choices.

Comment: Oh ok. This one: [www.cartovcl.com](http://www.cartovcl.com) installs the run-time .bpl into System32 (even for Delphi 10). I thought it was normal.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you copying files there? It should be treatead as the OS **private** directory. Unless you're installing a driver or the like, you should **never** write there. In XP you can only because you're running with Administrator privileges, try to use a plain user and you can't as well (since at least 2000, if not in NT already), but it will give you an error because it won't redirect the write. Unless you have a truly good reason to write there, I'd suggest to redesign your application to write in the proper place, instead of trying to find a way to write there. Anyway, it will fail anytime the user don't have the privileges and can't perform an elevation.

Comment: I'd bet that standard user in NT3.5 would not have had rights to write in system folders